# more link for angular ng-repeat show first few items

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, kendo-tooltip

I have a scenario where I have Array of objects and I wanted to display on first few of them (should be configurable).

```
var users = [{id:1234, name:'ABCD', role: 'XXX', lastLogin: 'XXXX'},
            {id:1235, name:'ABCDE', role: 'XXX', lastLogin: 'XXXX'},
            {id:1236, name:'ABCDF', role: 'XXX', lastLogin: 'XXXX'},
            {id:1237, name:'ABCDG', role: 'XXX', lastLogin: 'XXXX'},
            {id:1238, name:'ABCDH', role: 'XXX', lastLogin: 'XXXX'},
            {id:1239, name:'ABCDI', role: 'XXX', lastLogin: 'XXXX'}]

  <div ng-repeat="user in users">
       {{user.name}}({{user.id}}) {{$last ? ',' : ''}}
  </div>
```

I just want to display first 2 records as ABCD(1234), ABCDE(1235) + 4 more. and
display the other records on hover with a tooltip as

```
ABCDF(1236)
ABCDG(1237)
ABCDH(1238)
ABCDI(1239)
```

with each data on new line on tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)**

Like this

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | limitTo: limit">
       {{user.name}}({{user.id}}) {{$last ? ',' : ''}}
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.limit=2;
```

Comment: Anik Islam Abhi. Thank you for your reply. I know there was a way to limit the records but I actually want the easiest way to show the remaining records on tooltip from html page rather than angular